# Capistrano ssh_options aws deploy issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, capistrano

So I'm trying to deploy an app via capistrano, but despite trying several formats for referencing the pem file, it repeatedly asks me for my password.  The pem file is in the root directory of the rails project, named highlandsapptestdeploy.  Here is my code: also, I'm not sure if my server references are the correct ones or not?

```
set :application, "highlandsfacebookart"
set :repository,  "https://onenoc@bitbucket.org/onenoc/highlands-coffee-art-app.git"

set :user, 'deploy'
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}#"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(/highlandsapptestdeploy/highlandsfbkey.pem)


# set :scm, :git # You can set :scm explicitly or Capistrano will make an intelligent guess based on known version control directory names
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

role :web, "ec2-54-200-24-60.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "ec2-54-200-24-60.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "ec2-54-200-24-60.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
role :db,  "ec2-54-200-24-60.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling your username is incorrect. Are you sure it's "deploy"?

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need to have `ssh-agent` working on your machine.  Once the agent is working correctly you should be able to `ssh` into the machine without supplying a password or passphrase.  Then you'll need to tell Capistrano to forward the authentication from the agent.

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] => true
```

Comment: So I moved the highlandsfbkey.pem to ~/.ssh, and changed ssh_options[:keys] = %w(/highlandsapptestdeploy/highlandsfbkey.pem)
 to ssh_options[:keys] = %w(~/.ssh/highlandsfbkey.pem)
.  I then did ssh-add ~/.ssh/highlandsfbkey.pem, which was successful, and added your line, but it's still requesting a password.  What am I missing?

Comment: You still need to make sure that `ssh-agent` is running, and that you have authenticated yourself to the agent using `ssh-add`.

Comment: When I type ssh-agent I get SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-hGdAzqmk1870/agent.xxxx; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=xxxx; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid xxxx; that means it's running right?

Comment: Yep, now do `ssh-add`, then make sure that you can ssh to the server without a password/passphrase.

Comment: I did all that successfully, but it's still asking for password when I do cap deploy:setup :(.

Comment: If you can ssh to the same server(s) without a password/passphrase but Capistrano is still requiring a password then I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: I joined your chat room but you didn't respond.  Good luck.

Comment: Sorry that chat room was an accident, got it figured out.

Comment: I am having the same problem; I can ssh in without a password but Capistrano is still requiring it.  How did you fix it?

Comment: Lea, answer that I accepted was correct.  Make sure that the user matches, so if you are logging into ec2-user@xxx.com, your user should be ec2-user.